# Show that there is a $n\times n$ complex matrix $A$ with $A^r=I+N$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N$ be a nilpotent complex matrix . Let $r$ be a positive integer . Show that there is a $n\times n$ complex matrix $A$ with $A^r=I+N$

---

Since $N$ is nilpotent so $N^r=0$ for $r\ge 1$ from here i've no idea how i go through ???

**Edit** From comment : $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{r}}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_ix^i$ where $a_i={\frac{1}{r}} C n$ then $(1+x)=\left (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_ix^i \right)^{r}$ Now  take $x=N $ then $(I+N)=\left (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_iN^i \right)^{r}$ but my question is How can i write as matrix it $\left (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_iN^i \right)^{r}=A^r$ ???

Comment: Binomial theorem? (for fractional exponents)

Comment: can you elaborate plz .....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series